# Python dictionary with long key and value names

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with entries that would exceed 80 characters and I wanted to know if there is anything wrong in having the value of the key in a new line? ie:

```
from datetime import date

name = 'NAME'
mdy = date.today().strftime('%m%d%y')
d_my = date.today().strftime('%m-%y')

files = {
    '{}_FirstFile_{}.TXT'.format(name, mdy):
        '{}-FirstReport_{}.xlsx'.format(name, d_my),

    '{}_SecondFile_{}.TXT'.format(name, mdy):
        '{}-SecondReport_{}.xlsx'.format(name, d_my),

    '{}_ThirdFile_{}.TXT'.format(name, mdy):
        '{}-ThirdReport_{}.xlsx'.format(name, d_my),

    '{}_FourthFile_{}.TXT'.format(name, mdy):
        '{}-FourthReport_{}.xlsx'.format(name, d_my)
    }
```

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong.

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985563/python-best-practice-for-lists-dictionary-etc) for best practices for dictionaries.