# PEP8 formatting of dictionary with long values gives warning

Tags: python, pep8

I'm using [pycodestyle](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycodestyle) to lint, and I have the following code:

```
__gsignals__ = {
    "flashcards": (
                    GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST,
                    GObject.TYPE_NONE,
                    GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT)
    ),
    "game": ( # Gets E113 warning unexpected indent
                    GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST,
                    GObject.TYPE_NONE, (GObject.TYPE_STRING)
    )
}
```

As commented in the code, this formatting is gives me a warning, and suggests that the line should have no indent at all. I've tried a few different options, yet I can't seem to configure it to work out.

I've reviewed PEP8 documentation and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985563/python-best-formatting-practice-for-lists-dictionary-etc) - this formatting should be valid. Any idea what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is because of an extra parenthesis in the line `GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT)`. Removing the extra parenthesis returned no warnings on my computer.

Comment: aah so sorry very tired