# Line wrapping code for nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, line-breaks

with the new [Entity Resolution](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/5882651c-6377-4bc7-bfd7-0fd661d95abc/entity-resolution-in-skill-builder) in Alexa, nested dictionaries become very nested.  what's the most pythonic way to refer to a deeply nested value?  how do i write the code keeping within 79 characters per line?

this is what i currently have, and while it works, i'm pretty sure there is a better way:

```
if 'VolumeQuantity' in intent['slots']:
    if 'resolutions' in intent['slots']['VolumeQuantity']:
        half_decibels = intent['slots']['VolumeQuantity']['resolutions']['resolutionsPerAuthority'][0]['values'][0]['value']['name'].strip()
    elif 'value' in intent['slots']['VolumeQuantity']:
        half_decibels = intent['slots']['VolumeQuantity']['value'].strip()
```

Here is a partial sample of the json from alexa

```
  {
    "type": "IntentRequest",
    "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.9a...11",
    "timestamp": "2018-03-28T20:37:21Z",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "intent": {
      "name": "RelativeVolumeIntent",
      "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
      "slots": {
        "VolumeQuantity": {
          "name": "VolumeQuantity",
          "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
        },
        "VolumeDirection": {
          "name": "VolumeDirection",
          "value": "softer",
          "resolutions": {
            "resolutionsPerAuthority": [
              {
                "authority": "amzn1.er-authority.echo-blah-blah-blah",
                "status": {
                  "code": "ER_SUCCESS_MATCH"
                },
                "values": [
                  {
                    "value": {
                      "name": "down",
                      "id": "down"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
        }
      }
    },
    "dialogState": "STARTED"
  }
```

Comment: It's not super pretty, but you could break it across multiple lines so the indices form a column (in other words visually stack them)

Comment: you may also store the intermediate values of your nested dictionary which are accessed earlier in separate/meaningful variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python "best formatting practice" for lists, dictionary, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985563/python-best-formatting-practice-for-lists-dictionary-etc)

Comment: davedwards - i updated my question as i should have said nested dictionaries.  i think the possible duplicate you've linked is for large lists, but not excessive nesting (based on my original incorrectly worded question the duplicate would have applied)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably refering to nested dictionaries, lists only accept integer indices.

Anyway, (ab?)using the implied line continuation inside parentheses, I think this is pretty readable:

```
>>> d = {'a':{'b':{'c':'value'}}}
>>> (d
...     ['a']
...     ['b']
...     ['c']
... )
'value'
```

or alternatively

```
>>> (d['a']
...   ['b']
...   ['c'])
'value'
```

Comment: you are right, i was referring to nested dictionaries and not lists.  I have updated my question, as well as adding the sample json that I'm trying to read.  I did not know about the implied line continuation inside parentheses, that solves my problem!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use some **well-named intermediate variables** to make the program more readable as well as simpler and faster:

```
volumes = intent['slots']  # Pick meaningful names. I'm just guessing.
if 'VolumeQuantity' in volumes:
    quantity = volumes['VolumeQuantity']
    if 'resolutions' in quantity:
        half_decibels = quantity['resolutions']['resolutionsPerAuthority'][0]['values'][0]['value']['name'].strip()
    elif 'value' in quantity:
        half_decibels = quantity['value'].strip()
```

Second, you can write a **helper function** `nav(structure, path)` for navigating through these structures, so that, e.g.

```
nav(quantity, 'resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority.0.values.0.value.name')
```

splits up the given path and does the sequence of indexing/lookup operations. It could use `dict.get(key, default)` so you don't have to do so many `if key in dict` checks.